# Tidyverse suddenly collapses

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse

So my entire suite of tidyverse packages has decided it will no longer load. I did not do anything or change anything and suddenly scripts that worked last Wednesday are no longer working today.

Here is just a sample of the errors I am getting, when I try to load ggplot2:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 namespace ‘pillar’ 1.2.2 is being loaded, but >= 1.3.1 is required
```

So then I tried to install 'pillar' and got this

```
installing the source package ‘pillar’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/pillar_1.4.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 228815 bytes (223 KB)
downloaded 223 KB

'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/Program Files/R/R-34~1.1/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\60129180\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Temp\Rtmp8qhyCz/downloaded_packages/pillar_1.4.2.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘pillar’ had non-zero exit status
```

This seems to be an error of filepath specification, but it is a very recent one as the `install.packages()` function has worked fine up to now. I find it so disconcerting when something that used to work suddenly no longer works.

Judging by online activity someone within the tidyverse team has messed up big time. Errors should only happen when you change something.

Comment: I think you'll need to upgrade your version of R (3.4 is quite old) before attempting to upgrade `pillar`.

Comment: When you say "I did not do anything or change anything"... I assume you think updating or installing even seemingly unrelated packages is not changing anything?

Comment: @Dason I assume you did not read the second sentence of my post where I say "scripts that worked last Wednesday are no longer working today." The error preceded the update.  I updated the packages because the script I wrote using `dplyr::mutate()`, which worked fine in Wednesday threw an error today.

Comment: `'C:\Program' is not recognized ...` is a symptom of insufficient quoting in a batch script. Dunno what's going on there.

Comment: @Robert Dodier I know! It's especially strange since it is returning that error message from the automated `install.packages(foo)` command, despite the fact that last week the same command knew exactly where and how to specify the filepath to the library. a stone cold whodunnit. I'm starting to wonder whether the IT people where I work have done something to the system permissions without my knowledge.

Comment: @llewmills Yes I saw that part.  The thing is without updating *something* it would be impossible for that error to just happen out of nowhere.  Is it possible that before this happened a package got updated/installed that messed something else up?  Even if you think it's unrelated if a change occurred on your system then "I did not do anything or change anything" is not a true statement.  I'm pointing out that by trying to get people to think that that could possibly be true is getting in the way of understanding what happened to lead to your problem.